# python, networkx 2.0 'girvan_newman' is not defined

Tags: python, networkx

I get the error

```
NameError: name 'girvan_newman' is not defined
```

when try to use this algorithm in networkx 2.0.
Could someone help to fix this problem?

Comment: how did you import `networkx`? you need to prefix `girvan_newman` with whatever name you imported, such as `networkx.girvan_newman`..works for me in `networkx-2.0` and `python2.7`

Comment: echoing downshift: you need to provide sufficient code to reproduce this.  See [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

davedwards is right , you need to provide the missing import statements:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import community
communities_generator = community.girvan_newman(G)
```

Check https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/community.html